# How to pass nested object within an object in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pass a nested object within an object within a reducer.

im telling redux to pass `like` along with the `...post`. However it's giving me

> like is not defined.

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:0,
    postId:null
}

 case ADD_LIKE:
    console.log(action.id) // renders post id which is 2
    console.log(state.posts) // logs posts array
    console.log(state.posts)
        return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post => {
          if (post.id === action.id) {
                post.Likes.map( (like) => {
                    console.log(like); // renders like log
                })
            } 
            return {
                ...post,
                ...like, /// need to pass the like here but it says is not defined
                Likes: like.Likes + 1
            }      

        })
      };
```

`console.log(like); // renders this`
[image]

Like count are being called here

```
 <Like like={id} likes={Likes.length} />
```

Comment: Try to log ...like

Comment: in your return, like is not defined because it is not defined in initialstate, you can get that info maybe usaing `action.payload.data.post.like`

Comment: Thank you for responding, im looking to get the mappped (like) it can be called whatever. but its called like and that is what i want passed next to `...post`

Comment: and what if you 'save' that map? Likes aren't on the last scope, so if you 'store' them maybe you can call them later: `var a= post.Likes.map( (like) => {`

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an answer, explaining how you would better write it so like can become assessable. I learn and understand better that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem inside the return.

From the code, Here where you initialize the `like` variable (inside the map).

```
post.Likes.map( (like) => {
  console.log(like); // renders like log
})
```

So, the scope of like will not exist outside of it. 
But, you are trying to access it outside in return.

```
return {
   ...post,
   ...like,
   Likes: like.Likes + 1
}
```

**Edited**

If I understand your expectation correct. 
Here the solution.

```
return {
     ...post,
     ...post.Likes, 
     Likes: post.Likes.length + 1
}
```

Comment: what would be the solution. How would you better write the code so that i can access `...like`

Comment: `Likes: like.Likes + 1` is that just for likes count right? @randal

Comment: right that is correct. i want to use the like thats  mapped from post.Likes.map(like)

Comment: Updated the answer @randal

Comment: The like counts disappears after i click like. So their needs to be another way

Comment: i apperciate your effort though, ill share my like component.